# Android11 : how to check the value of MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION in settings?

Tags: android

My targetSdkVersion is 30 and I need to use every function of file manager,
so I add MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and open SystemSetting to get the permission.
But, I need to check the value of MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION in settings whether On or Off.

How can I check the value of the permission?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
boolean bAlreadyHavePermission;
                
bAlreadyHavePermission = ?;
                
if(bAlreadyHavePermission == false) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Hello, did you find the solution? I've pretty the same problem. My app targets from 30 API, and I need to manipulate files on device.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Environment.isExternalStorageManager()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#isExternalStorageManager())